# How do I block unknown attributes using an XSD and Xerces-C++?

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces-c

I have an XML schema that I'm validating against using Xerces-C++ 3.1.1. My XML documents validate normally. I can cause a validation failure by renaming an element, or a required attribute, so I'm pretty sure Xerces is doing the right thing with the schema.

However, the documents still validate if I add unknown attributes to an arbitrary element. I want validation to fail if there are any undefined attributes, but the XML Schema spec and Xerces documentation are not making it clear how to do this.

Here's my xerces parser setup:

```cpp
parser.setErrorHandler(&errorHandler);
parser.loadGrammar(schemaPath.c_str(), Grammar::SchemaGrammarType);
parser.setDoNamespaces(true);
parser.setDoSchema(true);
parser.setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
parser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);
```

The schema and documents don't use namespaces, and I'm not using attribute wildcards.

Here's a toy schema and document demonstrating the issue; this is the same as the top-level element in the actual schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qual\
ified">
  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="version"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This document validates against this schema, in spite of the unknown value attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Document value="blar" version="22"/>
```

I want validation to fail when there's an attribute present that's not in the schema, like this case.

Comment: You should show a minimal XSD and XML document that exhibit the problem.

Comment: +1 to show a minimal XSD. Not sure if when you talk about *"any element"* you mean any element or any (xs:any) element.

Comment: The behavior you describe would be consistent with the presence of an attribute wildcard in the relevant type definition; if you don't want unknown attributes to be accepted, don't use an attribute wildcard.

Comment: I've added an example of what I want to fail.

Comment: I have the same problem, let's see if there is a solution.